# Unparseable date exception for the date format 2020-12-31T11:46:18.000+00:00

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, datetime-parsing

How do i parse a date with the format 2020-12-31T11:46:18.000+00:00

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");

Date startDate = sdf.parse("2020-12-31T11:46:18.000+00:00");
```

I get Unparseable date exception. I have tried providing the Z without the quote but still it throws the exception.

The below code also doesn't work

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
```

Comment: I strongly recommend taht you do not use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are troublesome and fortunately long outdated. Use `OffsetDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html). Just `OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-12-31T11:46:18.000+00:00")` parses your string. You don’t even need to specify a formatter.